# Android SeekBar max position

Tags: xamarin.android, seekbar

I have problem with SeekBar in Android. I can't set max value. Ex. max value is 10001, but if I tried slide to max right position it returns 10000,96
I saw examples with setting paddings, removing custom styles, but it does not work for me
[result sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUNt6.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the result sample, I set the max with 100000100 like below and use a textview to how the value.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100000100"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I use the code below to get the value of seekbar.

```
    //Variables  
    SeekBar _seekBar;
    TextView _textView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        //LoadApplication(new App());

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainLayout);

        _seekBar = FindViewById<SeekBar>(Resource.Id.seekBar);
        _textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textview);

        _seekBar.ProgressChanged += (object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.FromUser)
            {
                _textView.Text = string.Format("SeekBar Value is {0}", e.Progress);
            }
        };

    }
```

I reproduce the value “100000096” you get.

It caused by the value. When I push the draggable thumb to the end, it looks like in the end. But, it is not. You could use another value.

[image]